# CUDA Program not working as fast as expected

Tags: c++, cuda

I've been experimenting with CUDA/C++ and decided to make an n body simulator. It simulates the gravitational attraction between 4096 particles. It runs at about 2 or 3 FPS and I'm not entirely sure why. The graphics card being used is a GTX 980 Ti, so I'd expect the program to run smoothly. I understand it's probably not optimised to the best of it's abilities, but I wouldn't have expected it to run so slowly.

The code is only supposed to be a prototype, so the code isn't neat (or properly written) by any means.

main.cu

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include "Particle.h"
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

#define N 4096
#define DT 0.00001
# define M_PI           3.14159265358979323846  /* pi */

using namespace std;

Particle p[N];

int frames = 0;
clock_t starttime = clock();
clock_t timepassed = 0;
bool first = true;
float fps = 0.0f;

__global__ void updateParticle(Particle* out, Particle *pin)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    double velx = 0;
    double vely = 0;
    out[i].mass = pin[i].mass;
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        if (i == j || pin[j].mass == 0 || pin[i].mass == 0)
            continue;
        double difx = pin[i].posx - pin[j].posx;
        double dify = pin[i].posy - pin[j].posy;
        double len = difx * difx + dify * dify;
        if (len == 0)
            continue;
        double force = (pin[i].mass * pin[j].mass) / len;
        len = sqrt(len);
        double dirx = -difx / len;
        double diry = -dify / len;
        dirx *= force;
        diry *= force;
        velx += (dirx / pin[i].mass + pin[i].velx) * DT;
        vely += (diry / pin[i].mass + pin[i].vely) * DT;
    }
    out[i].posx = pin[i].posx + velx;
    out[i].posy = pin[i].posy + vely;
    out[i].velx = pin[i].velx;
    out[i].vely = pin[i].vely;

    while (out[i].posx > 1)
        out[i].posx--;
    while (out[i].posx < -1)
        out[i].posx++;
    while (out[i].posy > 1)
        out[i].posy--;
    while (out[i].posy < -1)
        out[i].posy++;
}

void changeViewPort(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

}

void renderMore()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (p[i].mass == 0)
            continue;
        if (p[i].mass == 1)
            glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
        else
            glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
            double angle = 2 * M_PI * j / 300;
            double x = cos(angle) * 0.001;
            double y = sin(angle) * 0.001;
            x *= p[i].mass;
            y *= p[i].mass;
            glVertex2d(x + p[i].posx, y + p[i].posy);
        }
        glEnd();
    }

}

void render(void)
{
    if(first)
    {
        frames = 0;
        starttime = clock();
        first = false;
    }
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    renderMore();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    frames++;
}

void moveCuda(Particle* in, Particle* out)
{
    Particle *device_p = nullptr;
    Particle *device_res = nullptr;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    int size = N * sizeof(Particle);

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&device_res, size);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&device_p, size);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
    }

    // Copy input vectors from host memory to GPU buffers.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(device_p, in, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
    }

    updateParticle << <N / 1024, 1024 >> >(device_res, device_p);

    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "kernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching addKernel!\n", cudaStatus);
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(out, device_res, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
    }

    cudaFree(device_res);
    cudaFree(device_p);
}

void update(int)
{
    Particle temp[N] = {};
    moveCuda(p, temp);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        p[i] = temp[i];
    fps = (double)frames / ((clock() - starttime) / 1000);
        const string a = "FPS: " + to_string(fps);
        glutSetWindowTitle(a.c_str());

    glutTimerFunc(100.0 / 60, update, -1);
}

void idle()
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        p[i] = Particle();
    }
    // Initialize GLUT
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    // Set up some memory buffers for our display
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    // Set the window size
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
    // Create the window with the title "Hello,GL"
    glutCreateWindow("Hello World");
    // Bind the two functions (above) to respond when necessary
    glutReshapeFunc(changeViewPort);
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutTimerFunc(100.0 / 60, update, -1);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);


    // Very important!  This initializes the entry points in the OpenGL driver so we can 
    // call all the functions in the API.
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GLEW error");
        return 1;
    }

    render();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Particle.cpp

```
#include "Particle.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <host_defines.h>

Particle::Particle()
{
    posx = (((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX)) * 2) - 1;
    posy = (((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX)) * 2) - 1;
    velx = ((((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX)) * 2) - 1) / 4;
    vely = ((((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX)) * 2) - 1) / 4;
    mass = 1;
}
```

Particle.h

```
#pragma once

class Particle
{
public:
    Particle();
    void Update();
    double posx;
    double posy;
    double velx;
    double vely;
    double mass;
};
```

When I remove the line setting the graphics device it throws an error, but continues to run at 2-3 fps. This could indicate it's having trouble getting my graphics card, though I'm not sure what to make of this. It doesn't throw an error when I set it to cudaSetDevice(0). The graphics card is working, the monitor is connected to it and working.

If anyone could offer some pointers or advice I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: error: `Particle` has no member `p`.  Please provide a code that somebody could compile.

Comment: I've updated the code, it'll compile now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you may want to study the [CUDA nbody sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-n-body-simulation) as it will do a better job of exposing a well-written code than I will.  Also note that that sample includes a link to [this chapter](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch31.html) which is also instructive.

I'll present a code that seems to run a lot faster than your original code.  Here are the general strategies I applied:

1. Make sure you are building a *release* project, not a *debug* project.
2. Don't do unnecessary `cudaMalloc`/`cudaFree` or `cudaMemcpy` operations. It's best to perform these allocations once, and reuse them.  Since you're not modifying anything (positions, velocities) in host code, it also means that we don't really need to update the device for every iteration of `moveCuda`.  Just leave the data on the device.  This cuts us down to a single `cudaMemcpy` operation so we can perform our OpenGL stuff (but see below).  I seemed to get about a 3x boost out of this.  I've also implemented a "ping-pong" buffer strategy so as to avoid unnecessary copying.
3. Use `float` instead of `double`.  This has a couple benefits.  First, it cuts down on memory traffic, as you are retrieving half as much data.  Second, the GPU you are using has dramatically higher throughput (math operations) for `float` than `double`.  I don't really think this is a compute bound kernel, so I think the memory traffic is the bigger issue.  I seemed to get about another 3x boost out of this.
4. Convert your particles from AoS to SoA.  This topic is covered here on the `cuda` tag as well as many other places, so I'm not going to review it here.  I haven't done this fully, instead I have done a partial conversion (removing the mass to a separate array) and then used a "vector load" strategy for the remaining `float4` quantity of velocity x/y and position x/y.  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451832/cuda-profiler-reports-inefficient-global-memory-access/42451933#42451933) is an example answer that discusses both AoS->SoA transformation and why it is valuable, as well as the vector load "shortcut" I took here.
5. 4096 is a relatively small number of threads for a modern GPU.  You may witness a small benefit by switching from 1024-thread blocks to 512-thread blocks.  This gives the kernel a slightly better opportunity to fill up available SMs on your GPU.  If you only had 4 or fewer SMs, this wouldn't make much difference, but your 980 Ti has **22** SMs, so our best chance to witness highest performance would be to put at least 1 block on every SM.  So you might even want to try blocks of 256 threads (for 16 total threadblocks).
6. This is a fairly "expensive" set of calculations:

   ```
   len = sqrt(len);
   double dirx = -difx / len;
   double diry = -dify / len;
   ```

   it turns out that `rsqrtf()` is about as easy to calculate as `sqrtf()`, and with that we can turn the subsequent floating-point divide operations into floating-point multiply operations.

With these basic steps, I was able to get to about 30fps on a very old GPU, you should probably witness something better than that.  I was working on linux, but I don't believe any of the changes I made should "break" under windows.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <time.h>
#define N 4096
#define DT 0.00001
#define M_PI           3.14159265358979323846  /* pi */


class Particle
{
public:
    Particle();
    float4 p;
};

Particle::Particle()
{
    p.x = (((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX)) * 2) - 1;
    p.y = (((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX)) * 2) - 1;
    p.z = ((((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX)) * 2) - 1) / 4;
    p.w = ((((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX)) * 2) - 1) / 4;
}
const int size = N * sizeof(Particle);


using namespace std;

Particle p[N];
float pmass[N];
Particle *d_p1, *d_p2;
float *d_pmass1, *d_pmass2;
int ping_pong = 0;
float et;
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
int frames = 0;
clock_t starttime = clock();
clock_t timepassed = 0;
bool first = true;
float fps = 0.0f;

__global__ void updateParticle(Particle * __restrict__  out, float * __restrict__ pmass_out,  const Particle * __restrict__ pin, const float * __restrict__ pmass_in)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    float velx = 0;
    float vely = 0;
    Particle my_i = pin[i];
    float my_mass_i = pmass_in[i];
    pmass_out[i] = my_mass_i;
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        float my_mass_j = pmass_in[j];
        if (i == j || my_mass_i == 0 || my_mass_j == 0)
            continue;
        Particle my_j = pin[j];
        float difx = my_i.p.x - my_j.p.x;
        float dify = my_i.p.y - my_j.p.y;
        float len = difx * difx + dify * dify;
        if (len == 0)
            continue;
        float force = (my_mass_i * my_mass_j) / len;
        len = rsqrtf(len);
        float dirx = -difx * len;
        float diry = -dify * len;
        dirx *= force;
        diry *= force;
        velx += (dirx / my_mass_i + my_i.p.z) * DT;
        vely += (diry / my_mass_i + my_i.p.w) * DT;
    }
    Particle my_out_i = my_i;
    my_out_i.p.x = my_i.p.x + velx;
    my_out_i.p.y = my_i.p.y + vely;
    my_out_i.p.z = my_i.p.z;
    my_out_i.p.w = my_i.p.w;

    if (my_out_i.p.x > 1)
        my_out_i.p.x = 1;
    if (my_out_i.p.x < -1)
        my_out_i.p.x = -1;
    if (my_out_i.p.y > 1)
        my_out_i.p.y = 1;
    if (my_out_i.p.y < -1)
        my_out_i.p.y = -1;
    out[i] = my_out_i;
}

void changeViewPort(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

}

void renderMore()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (pmass[i] == 0)
            continue;
        if (pmass[i] == 1)
            glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
        else
            glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
            double angle = 2 * M_PI * j / 300;
            double x = cos(angle) * 0.001;
            double y = sin(angle) * 0.001;
            x *= pmass[i];
            y *= pmass[i];
            glVertex2d(x + p[i].p.x, y + p[i].p.y);
        }
        glEnd();
    }

}

void render(void)
{
    if(first)
    {
        frames = 0;
        starttime = clock();
        first = false;
    }
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    renderMore();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    frames++;
}

void moveCuda(Particle* in, Particle* out)
{
    Particle *d_pi;
    Particle *d_po;
    float *d_pmassi, *d_pmasso;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    if (ping_pong) {
      d_pi = d_p2;
      d_po = d_p1;
      d_pmassi = d_pmass2;
      d_pmasso = d_pmass1;
      ping_pong = 0;}
    else {
      d_pi = d_p1;
      d_po = d_p2;
      d_pmassi = d_pmass1;
      d_pmasso = d_pmass2;
      ping_pong = 1;}
    cudaEventRecord(start);
    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
    }
    updateParticle << <N / 256, 256 >> >(d_po, d_pmasso,  d_pi, d_pmassi);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "kernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching addKernel!\n", cudaStatus);
    }
    cudaEventRecord(stop);

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(out, d_po, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
    }
    //cudaEventRecord(stop);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&et, start, stop);

}

void update(int)
{
    Particle temp[N] = {};
    moveCuda(p, temp);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        p[i] = temp[i];
    char a[64];
    fps = (float)frames / ((clock() - starttime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        sprintf(a, "FPS: %f, et: %f\0", fps, et);
        glutSetWindowTitle(a);

    glutTimerFunc(100.0 / 60, update, -1);
}

void idle()
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        p[i] = Particle();
        pmass[i] = 1;
    //    p[i].p();
    }
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_p2, size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_p1, size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_pmass2, N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_pmass1, N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(d_p1, p, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_pmass1, pmass, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaEventCreate(&start); cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    // Initialize GLUT
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    // Set up some memory buffers for our display
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    // Set the window size
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
    // Create the window with the title "Hello,GL"
    glutCreateWindow("Hello World");
    // Bind the two functions (above) to respond when necessary
    glutReshapeFunc(changeViewPort);
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutTimerFunc(100.0 / 60, update, -1);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);


    // Very important!  This initializes the entry points in the OpenGL driver so we can
    // call all the functions in the API.
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GLEW error");
        return 1;
    }

    render();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't claim that this is defect free code, (I think yours was not), but it seemed to behave graphically about the same as your original code.  For example, in your code, you have this at the end of the kernel:

```
out[i].velx = pin[i].velx;
out[i].vely = pin[i].vely;
```

that doesn't look right to me, but it's not central to performance being discussed here.

If you know that your masses are always 1 or 0, then you could make substantial additional optimizations to this code, but I've not pursued that.

As an additional note, you may want to think about a CUDA/OpenGL interop strategy to get rid of the device->host copy that remains here, and move the data permanently to the GPU.  Again, the CUDA nbody sample code can be a roadmap, and if you want to get started with CUDA/GL interop, I think [this presentation](http://www.nvidia.com/content/gtc/documents/1055_gtc09.pdf) is a bit dated, but a good starting point.